# Can I post this on the main site?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags, questions

Can I post this on the main site? There is a sweater involved.

If so, what would be the appropriate tags?

[image]

(Click picture for the link.)

NB: The deadline almost certainly refers to Central European Time.

Comment: No, because it would be an engineering homework problem :P Falls afoul of _two_ policies (wonder if they cancel each other out?)

Comment: It looks like it broke at the join. The strength of the join would be best determined experimentally. So, to answer the question, go around breaking identical signs with a calibrated hammer. This may not make you popular with TU Delft, nor with Gemeente Delft, but it will make you right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know that this works as a main-site question, per se. After all, just asking for someone to do the calculations runs afoul of the HW policy, and asking for people to submit solutions that are expected to vary may even run afoul of big lists.

I think a hypothetical site where this is on-topic as-is would be to Physics.SE as Codegolf.SE is to SO.

That said, it's a cute problem, and it reminds me of the types of things we were expected to figure out at the drop of a hat in an order-of-magnitude physics class I took as an undergrad (one of the best and hardest classes I've ever taken). I think it'd be fun to discuss in chat if nowhere else.

And of course, any question that gets down to the *concepts* at work here ("Could vortices have reduced the naive estimate of pressure?" "Is this method for finding the elastic limit of metal sound?") *would* be welcome on the main site.

Comment: Okidoki. I'll wait and see which winner/answer they'll choose. Perhaps that may result in a question here on main on the concepts involved. But, at such time, there won't be any sweater to win anymore. :)